# Securing A Google Sheet With A Custom Generated License Key

Tags: html, google-sheets, firebase-authentication

I am trying to secure a heavily customized Google sheet so that it may be licensed out for personal or commercial use, and am looking to secure the sheet by generating and sending the user a license key that they may paste into the sheet to unlock it.

I have checked this answer below for how to create the dialog box/popup, but am not sure if this would sufficiently stop people from just closing it out/bypassing verification.

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/80213/create-a-popup-in-google-spreadsheet

I'm also considering tying all of this into Firebase for ease of use.

Has anyone every done this before or know if Google sheets has this capability?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method of creating a dialog box or pop-up **won't work** because the user who will get access to the sheet can just simply close it.

According to the [Dialogs and Sidebars in G Suite Documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) documentation:

> An alert is a pre-built dialog box that opens inside a Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, or Forms editor. It displays a message and an "OK" button; a title and alternative buttons are optional. It is similar to calling `window.alert()` in client-side JavaScript within a web browser.

Therefore, what you are trying to do cannot be done.

By default, all the Spreadsheets you create can be viewed and edited **only by yourself**.

The only way to restrict or extend the access to a Spreadsheet is by using the **sharing settings**.

[image]

If you want to protect a certain **range** or **sheet** from **editing**, you can **protect a sheet or a range**. Please note that this still **allows** the viewing of the sheet or the range.